# get content file in java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I used this method to download and get content type

```java
    @GetMapping("/downloadFile/")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadFile(@RequestParam String fileName, HttpServletRequest request) {
        // Load file as Resource
        Resource resource = fileStorageService.loadOneFileAsResource(fileName);

        // Try to determine file's content type
        String contentType = null;
        try {
            contentType = request.getServletContext().getMimeType(resource.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.info("Could not determine file type.");
        }

        // Fallback to the default content type if type could not be determined
        if(contentType == null) {
            contentType = "application/octet-stream";
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(contentType))
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + resource.getFilename() + "\"")
                .body(resource);
    }
```

But always detect my content "application/octet-stream", what is problem and what should I do?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the logging. If the resource is packed, say in a .war, there is no File.

Comment: if I were you, I would use either MimeTypesFileTypeMap or Apache Tika. Please check it [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-file-mime-type)

Answer (score 1):

You can download the file, save it and then use the following:

```
Path path = Paths.get(resource.getURI());
String contentType = Files.probeContentType(path);
```

This should give you the content type. Look over [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-file-mime-type).

Comment: @JoopEggen agree and changed

Comment: I changed try part to this:                                                                                         String contentType = null;
        try {

            Path path = Paths.get(resource.getURI());
            contentType = Files.probeContentType(path);

        }                                                                                                                                     but nothing changed and I dont get proper contet type!